# How can I create publishable tables of my logistic regression graph on R

Tags: r

I have created a logistic regression model, and would like to export the data into Word. My logistic regression model has this code:

```
glm_May_2010 <- glm(EB734_May_2010$trust ~ EB734_May_2010$EU_satisfaction, data = EB734_May_2010, family = "binomial")
```

Any ideas on how I can export the summary of this regression model for Word? Thanks :)

Comment: Could you please `dput(EB734_May_2010)` and add the output to your question in order to help you?

Comment: Lot's of possible options but if you just want the summary table then try using `broom` and `flextable`.  This code will generate a document

```r
flextable::save_as_docx(flextable::flextable(broom::tidy(glm_May_2010)), path = "pretty.docx")

```